# change Twig concatenation delimiter

Tags: twig, concatenation, delimiter

twig uses `~` for its concatenation, is there any way to change this to another symbol?

I know there is a way to change other delimiters, like, the blocks, comments, etc, but I didn't find anything on concatenation. So if someone knows, that would be great!

Comment: If it's fine if the `~`-operator keeps it's default behaviour, you could register a new one that does the same, see [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#operators)

Comment: And the class should be `Twig_Node_Expression_Binary_Concat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the delimeters your talking about, the TwigLexer only define this symbols:

```
$this->options = array_merge(array(
    'tag_comment' => array('{#', '#}'),
    'tag_block' => array('{%', '%}'),
    'tag_variable' => array('{{', '}}'),
    'whitespace_trim' => '-',
    'interpolation' => array('#{', '}'),
), $options);
```

As @DarkBee mentioned, you could define your own operator using https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#operators

You can found already defined operators on this php class to help you define your own:
`vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php` class `Twig_Extension_Core::getOperators`

Your operator would be

```
class Project_Twig_Extension extends Twig_Extension
{
    public function getOperators()
    {
        return array(
            array(),
            array(
               '~' => array('precedence' => 40, 'class' => 'Twig_Node_Expression_Binary_Concat', 'associativity' => Twig_ExpressionParser::OPERATOR_LEFT),
            ),
        );
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Alright, it works great!
I have however, one problem remaining.
The delimiter I wanted was a semi colon, and this works perfectly. However my phpstorm doesnt like it, it underlines it red and then decolors all the remaining code. 

It doesnt give any errors itself, it's just my IDE that doesnt like it. Any way to fix this?

Comment: I don't think the twig or symfony plugin supports it. Are you using the 2017.3.4?

Comment: I don't really know if I'm honest.